# multiselect checkbox dropdown call an Event when checked and Unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

this is my html content when i checked a multiple dropdown checkbox i want to call a java script function but its not working.    i am using multiselect jquery [multiselect jquery](http://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/)

```
<select name="langOpt2[]" multiple id="langOpt2">
    <?php foreach($property_type as $row)  {  ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['type']; ?>" onchange="selectsearch(this.checked,'property_type',this.value);"><?php echo $row['type']; ?> </label>
       </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

my javascript code is -

```
<script language="javascript">
function selectsearch(val2,val1,state_id)
  {

  var title=state_id;
  alert('action');
  $.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/property/propertysearch',
  data: {'title':title,'name':val1,'status':val2 }, // change this to send js object
  type: "post",
  success: function(data){
  //document.write(data); just do not use document.write
  console.log(data);
  document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = data; 
  document.getElementById('search').style.display  = 'block'; 
  document.getElementById("search1").style.display = 'none';
  },

  error: function()
  {
  alert("Fail")
  }

  });

  }
 </script>
```

Comment: You got any errors in the console?

Comment: No when I checked no js call. Nothing happens when checked

Comment: Try changing `onchange()` to `onclick()`

Comment: Tried but wrong parameter passing. $this.checked undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="langOpt2[]" multiple id="langOpt2" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="type1" onclick="selectsearch(this.selected, 'property_type', this.value)">Type 1</option>
    <option value="type2" onclick="selectsearch(this.selected, 'property_type', this.value)">Type 2</option>
</select>
```

change `this.checked` to `this.selected`